# how to remove KeyStore security prompt

Tags: blackberry, ssl

i am trying to develop an app which tries to call a https(godaddy ssl) url.
i have successfully installed certificate in key store using this code.

```
 public void addCertToDeviceKeyStore(Certificate certificate) {
        KeyStore keyStore = DeviceKeyStore.getInstance();
        // check if certificate is not already in the DeviceKeyStore
        if (!keyStore.isMember(certificate)) {
            try {

                String SFN = certificate.getSubjectFriendlyName();
                CertificateStatus CS = certificate.getStatus();
                keyStore.set(null, SFN, certificate, CS, keyStore.getTicket());

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

after adding certificate also 
why i am getting security prompt for keystore password and for trusting the connection?

is there any way to avoid these security prompts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this by making your device find the root certificate. There is a problem with godaddy certificate where the BlackBerry can't find the root.

You need to edit the .htaccess file to point to the root certificate.

http://help.godaddy.com/topic/742/article/5238

Here is an example of solution, with the same kind of problem but on another platform.

http://blog.boxedice.com/2009/05/11/godaddy-ssl-certificates-and-cannot-verify-identity-on-macsafari/