# Which verisign SSL Certificate should I go with?

Tags: iphone, android, blackberry, ssl, verisign

I'm looking an option to buy a verisign ssl certificate for my company.
previously we were using godaddy but godaddy ssl is not installed on blackberry. we can install manually or programmatically but its a extra over head for users. 
you can [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510499/how-to-remove-keystore-security-prompt) what problem we are facing with goddady

So now we are moving to verisign ssl certificate. many different verisign ssl certificates are 
available.
http://www.verisign.com/ssl/buy-ssl-certificates/compare-ssl-certificates/index.html

So my question is Which verisign SSL Certificate should I go with, that covers most of the
blackberry , iphone and android devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that a site like Amazon.com is not using anything better than what Verisign is calling "Secure Site Pro" (Amazon does not have [the green bar](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/ie/ev/security.mspx)).  Perhaps if your company is quite small, you are engaged in e-commerce, and you need all the extra credibility you can get - then go for something better.  But honestly, I suspect most surfers have little regard for the green bar.  And if you are not using this for e-commerce, then you really could go with the lesser certs.

Comment: we are not bother about green bar. we are only bother about that it should be already install in most of the blackberry, iphone and android. user need not to install.

Comment: Those devices will already have the root certificate for verisign.  All of them will work on all of those devices.